# BI Publisher report using RTF template

Tags: bi-publisher

Detail about the scenario is like I am clubbing the 10 tables queries into one data model after that in RTF template I have develop 5 different reports with the sample XML of same data-model but here I need to filter each report with 5 different parameter. which, I don't get exactly how to achieve ....?

For example :-  1st report to be filter with booking-date  & 2nd report to be filter with category-id='1001' & 3rd report to be filter with category-id in ('2001','2003','2004'.......)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the filter criteria within square brackets in your foor loops.

eg: `<?for-each:root[category-id='1001]?>`

Will filter only those nodes which meet that criteria. Of course the actual command will depend on the schema of your data.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am new to BI publisher can u more elaborate your answer. like which are the places to assign parameter in RTF template

Comment: got it thank you.

As u said early about RTF Template parameter. the same way I wanted to filter data in Excel template as well. please advice. how to ?

Comment: In your excel template, once you have added the loop tables, use excel's Formula -> Name Manager  to see the different XDO functions. There you can try giving the filter criteria in the node name. Look for XDO_GROUP functions.

Comment: ok I got you. can u put an example like how I can give filter . for example I wanted to filter excel template data with category=101 and category=102